# Streaming output log from Gearman worker

Tags: php, stream, queue, gearman

I am building a Gearman job which executes a command with real-time output stream (STDOUT). I am using PHP.

My Rest API needs to return a temporary URL where client can connect to see the output.

```
REST API call.
    creates Gearman background job
    return 'http://example.com/status?job=123'


HTTP call to status?123
    disables cache
    output output from job produced so far
    reads and flushes any further output
```

The only way I've found so far is by using `jobStatus()` but it only gives progression information. I also do not want to introduce expensive database pulling techniques.

Can this be done in Gearman or some other server in a simple way? If there is another queue implementation which can be used instead with PHP?

Comment: `jobStatus` is the only way to retrieve job status information. If you want to send another data you can write to memcache from a job function and then retrieve information  on a job info page